# Make: recursive make ignores -s

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

observe the difference between `make silent` and `make noisy`.  I asked make to be silent on the bar rule, but it is only silent on the foo rule, too.

What am I missing?

```
noisy:
    @make foo

silent:
    @make -s foo

foo:
    @make -s bar

bar:
    @echo bar
```

running it:

```
$ make silent
bar

$ make noisy
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/s'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/s'
bar
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/s'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/s'
```

I expected the `noisy` foo -> bar call to not print "Entering directory"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options are passed from a parent make to a sub-make using the [MAKEFLAGS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) environment variable, to which the sub-make adds the command-line flags it received. If a sub-make doesn't receive `-s` (`--silent`), `-w` (`--print-directory`), or `--no-print-directory`, it [automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/_002dw-Option.html) adds `-w` to its own MAKEFLAGS. The order of precedence for enabling and disabling directory printing seems to be (from weakest to strongest) `-s`, `-w`, `--no-print-directory`.

So, when you run `make silent`, the first recursive call adds `-s` to MAKEFLAGS, and the second call knows not to touch the flags. However, when you run `make noisy`, the first recursive call adds `-w` to MAKEFLAGS since you didn't tell it not to be silent, and from then on, `-s` won't have the effect you're looking for. You can use `--no-print-directory` instead, since it overrides `-w`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Weird, but at least I understand.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you showed the output you see and explained exactly which aspects you think are wrong.  Also your statement *but it is only silent on the foo rule, too* is hard to interpret/understand.  So, I don't really know what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

However, I will say that `-s` only makes a difference with recipe lines that are not prefixed with `@`.  If a recipe line is prefixed with `@` then it will never be printed regardless of whether you specify `-s` or not.  Since all your recipe lines are prefixed with `@`, using `-s` or not will make no difference at all.

Maybe that will help you understand what you're seeing.

Also, FYI you should never use literal `make` when invoking make recursively.  Always use the `$(MAKE)` variable, instead.

Comment: edited the post with a bit more detail.  It's the "entering directory" that I don't want to see.  yes I know to use $(MAKE), I was simplifying to ensure the weird flag semantics of recursive make would not affect it.

Comment: @TimHockin Add [`--no-print-directory`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary).